# Indy. Error posting String with %

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy

I am using Indy 9.00.10 under Delphi 7.

I use [TIdMultiPartFormDataStream](http://www.e-iter.net/knowledge/indy9/007579.html) to post some data using **TIdHTTP**. When I try to post some param with a text value including % in it, for instance '100% brand' it raises "No Argument for format %".

It seems to me that it is calling some format function to the value I am trying to post and it expects every % to be a placeholder, wich is not my case.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a very old version of Indy.  The last release of Indy 9 was 9.0.50, which is available in [Indy's SVN](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.EN.aspx).  This issue was fixed in 9.0.13.

If you do not want to upgrade, then a workaround is to double up any `'%'` characters in your field data so they get formatted as a single `'%'` character, eg:

```
Stream.AddFormField('FieldName', StringReplace(FieldValue, '%', '%%', [rfReplaceAll]));
```

Comment: +1 Perfect. I upgraded and it solved not only this issue. Providing a solution for the old version as well was very good too. Thanks.